# To redirect to login page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have two controller login and student.When i click seatingreport4 from localhost it redirect to student not to login.But i want to redirect to login .Pls help me.

in myconfig:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/seatingreport4/';
```

Comment: Wheres the code that redirects the user?

Comment: i mean when i click seatingreport4 it moves to student

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just go to `application/config/routes.php` and set the value for    `default` controller 
    $route['default_controller'] = "index";

to whichever controller you want to put. Here in this case set its value to the function that loads the login view.

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to check session or login is done or not. if loin done and session set then report else login page.

Comment: Where to check the session

Comment: when user login save session.then check in your "seatingreport4" page that user set session or not ?